# How to find a setuid file by using the time which it was created

Tags: opensuse, gnome-terminal, setuid

I'm a newbie to `OpenSUSE` and playing around with the terminal commands.

What i have already done is to create a .txt file and set a `setuid` for it and hidden it.

What i wanted to know is, how can i find that particular file using the time which it has been created?

ie: Files which has been modified within 30 minutes of time.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
find / -type f -mmin +0 -mmin -30 -perm +6000
```